# Different results for same date string using lubridate package in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a vector of strings:

```
str <- c("01-", "01-just researching", "01-1-3 months", "01-immediately", "01-4-6 months", "01-more than 12 months", "01-7-12 months")
```

If I parse it using `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` package, it would get different result if I only parse the first 6 strings. Why?

```
parse_date_time(str, "dmy")
[1] NA               NA               "2003-01-01 UTC" NA               "2006-04-01 UTC"
[6] NA               "2012-07-01 UTC"

parse_date_time(str[1:6], "dmy")
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Why are you trying to parse them into dates? `str` doesn't look like dates at all to me.

Comment: @RichardScriven This is some typical dirty data within a larger real data set where most are more formatted like "01-May-13", then I encounter this weird situation so I'm curious about what happened.

Comment: You might try getting them into the proper format first.  It seems you may have confused the parser :)

Comment: `parse_date_time` in my experience is temperamental. It seems to try different formats depending on proportionally how often they are present in a vector. Therefore taking a subset changes the result. Trying to automate messy date fixing seems like a hell of a task, and I admire anyone that attempts it, but I think there is always gonna be some manual handling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a function `guess_formats` which is so kind to explain which elements match the template. As you can see only the last string does:

```
guess_formats(str, "dmy", print_matches = TRUE)

#                               dmy              
# [1,] "01-"                    ""               
# [2,] "01-just researching"    ""               
# [3,] "01-1-3 months"          ""               
# [4,] "01-immediately"         ""               
# [5,] "01-4-6 months"          ""               
# [6,] "01-more than 12 months" ""               
# [7,] "01-7-12 months"         "%d-%m-%y months"
```

I think the rest is obvious.